# Create Django Model Instance using POST method in another Python Script

Tags: python, django, django-models, server

So I have a django app with some models which I can manipulate via admin and also through a client facing site, like add instances etc. However, I would like to try something a little different from that. I have a Python script that uses POST and JSON objects based on those self same models and I would like to be able to run it, connect to my django app server via a port and create new instances of my models (essentially without using Admin or my client page). Any ideas how I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what the script does is simple, it may be easiest just to create a view which receives the JSON, processes it, and returns a `JsonResponse`.

e.g.

```
def create_object(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        # Do something with the data - e.g. create a model instance
        MyModel.objects.create(**data)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'created'})
```

Alternatively, if the script does more complicated things or if you intended to expand it in future, you may be best to expose your site via a REST API using something such as [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

With Django Rest Framework, you can fairly rapidly build CRUD based APIs around your models using components such as [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)s and [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)s and expose them over REST with minimal code.